# Создание плоскости чертежа от трех координат

Tags: python

Нужно сделать программку, которая будет создавать 3 проекции тела по введенному уравнению.
 В принципе, у меня есть план как её создать, вот только обычный канвас даёт только две координаты X и Y.
А мне нужны 3 плоскости: X-Y, Z-X и Z-Y.
Ну в общем можно ли как-то добавить в канвас третью координату, скажем, от центра? Или как еще можно выкрутиться тут?
Библиотеку для построения графиков использовать нельзя.

Comment: Непонятно. Для проекции двух координат достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так ведь проекция - это и есть отображение объекта в пространстве меньшей размерности.

От вас требуется построить ТРИ проекции объекта на ТРИ плоскости, как здесь, например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]